# How to make parent and child bidirectional pipe in C

Tags: c, pipe, fork

I am trying to do a bidirectional pipe, the parent sends n number (int) to the child and the child return them doubled. I can't figure out what's my error?
I scanned the number n is the parent, sent it through fd1[1], and then proceeded to send those n numbers for the child to double.
In the child, I read the number n and then for every number I read, I double and send back.

```
int main(){
    int pid,n,c,p,k,nbread;
    char buf1[2], buf2[2];
    int fd1[2], fd2[2];
    pipe(fd1);
    pipe(fd2);
    pid=fork();
    if(pid==0){
        close(fd1[1]);
        close(fd2[0]);
        read(fd1[0],buf2,sizeof(int));
        n = atoi(buf2);
        for(int i = 0; i<n;i++){
            nbread = read(fd1[0],buf2,sizeof(int));
            sleep(3);
            if(nbread == -1)
            exit(1);
            c = atoi(buf2);
            c = c*2;
            sprintf(buf2,"%d",c);
            write(fd2[1],buf2, sizeof(int));
        }
        close(fd1[0]);
        close(fd2[1]);
    }
    close(fd1[0]);
    close(fd2[1]);
    printf("Enter integer: ");
    scanf("%d",&p);
    sprintf(buf1,"%d",p);
    write(fd1[1],buf1,sizeof(int));
    sleep(3);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        sprintf(buf1,"%d",i);
        write(fd1[1],buf1,sizeof(int));
        read(fd2[0],buf1,sizeof(int));
        printf("number is: %s",buf1);
    }
    close(fd1[1]);
    close(fd2[0]);
    wait(NULL);
    return 0;}
```

Comment: Have you done any debugging?

Comment: A 'bidirectional pipe' is different from using two pipes to have bidirectional communication between two processes.

Comment: @benc output:
Enter integer: 3
Enter integer:

Comment: You need to have the child code exit, rather than also try to execute the parent code.  It's easier if you use functions — `be_childish()` and `be_parental()` are the names I normally use because they're the same length.  Your buffers (`buf1` and `buf2`) are tiny; only big enough for single-digit numbers.  OK if that's what you really intend to enter, but very brittle (and unnecessarily brittle).

Comment: The second `Enter integer` is because the child continues into the parent's code after it's finished closing its pipes.

Comment: I added exit(0) to child, fixed the second Enter integer, but nothing else is printed @JonathanLeffler

Comment: You have lines like: `write(fd1[1],buf1,sizeof(int));
        read(fd2[0],buf1,sizeof(int));` — but the buffers are of size 2, which is rarely the same as `sizeof(int)`.  You invoke undefined behaviour when you read or write beyond the ends of the arrays as shown.

Comment: The rest of the trouble is that the parent reads a number into `p`, but then uses a for loop using `n` as the upper bound.  Since `n` is uninitialized, you get indeterminate (undefined) behaviour.  Use `p`.  Declare your variables when you're about to use them; that'll help avoid the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixing the parent loop to test `p` and not `n` fixes the main problems.  Making sure that the buffers are big enough is a good idea too.  Writing the whole buffer is OK though not necessarily ideal.

This code works; it has more debugging output in it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    int pid, n, c, p, k, nbread;
    char buf1[12], buf2[12];
    int fd1[2], fd2[2];
    pipe(fd1);
    pipe(fd2);
    pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0)
    {
        close(fd1[1]);
        close(fd2[0]);
        read(fd1[0], buf2, sizeof(buf2));
        n = atoi(buf2);
        printf("Child read %d\n", n);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            printf("child dozes...\n");
            sleep(3);
            printf("child wakes...\n");
            nbread = read(fd1[0], buf2, sizeof(buf2));
            if (nbread == -1)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "child exits after read failure\n");
                exit(1);
            }
            c = atoi(buf2);
            c = c * 2;
            sprintf(buf2, "%d", c);
            write(fd2[1], buf2, sizeof(buf2));
            printf("Child wrote [%s]\n", buf2);
        }
        close(fd1[0]);
        close(fd2[1]);
        printf("Child done\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        close(fd1[0]);
        close(fd2[1]);
        printf("Enter integer: ");
        scanf("%d", &p);
        sprintf(buf1, "%d", p);
        write(fd1[1], buf1, sizeof(buf1));
        printf("Parent wrote [%s]\n", buf1);
        printf("parent dozes...\n");
        sleep(3);
        printf("parent wakes...\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < p; i++)
        {
            sprintf(buf1, "%d", i);
            write(fd1[1], buf1, sizeof(buf1));
            printf("parent wrote [%s]\n", buf1);
            read(fd2[0], buf2, sizeof(buf2));
            printf("number is: %s\n", buf2);
        }
        close(fd1[1]);
        close(fd2[0]);
        wait(NULL);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
Enter integer: 4
Parent wrote [4]
parent dozes...
Child read 4
child dozes...
parent wakes...
parent wrote [0]
child wakes...
Child wrote [0]
child dozes...
number is: 0
parent wrote [1]
child wakes...
Child wrote [2]
child dozes...
number is: 2
parent wrote [2]
child wakes...
Child wrote [4]
child dozes...
number is: 4
parent wrote [3]
child wakes...
Child wrote [6]
Child done
number is: 6
```

The code puts the child code and parent code into separate `if` and `else` blocks.  It doesn't detect failures in `pipe()` or `fork()` which is suboptimal.  The child `exit(0)` is not crucial any more.